# Laravel 5.4 Redirection in the server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel 5.4 project under the folder www of Wampserver64.

The project folder name is AxilogicV2.

When I visit localhost/AxilogicV2 it will take me to the login screen, but after login succeeds it takes me to 'localhost/'. (The form should make a post request to itself ('/') and will be redirected to ('/view').

Every redirection ignores 'AxilogicV2'.

Example: localhost/AxilogicV2/view/9408 => localhost/view/9408.

Here is my .htaccess file. I tried a bunch of redirect rules but didn't work.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /AxilogicV2

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

In httpd.conf file Rewrite is enabled and Override is set to All.

Edit: I took out the index.php from public folder and made appropriate corrections so that it will find the right `bootstrap` folder and access autoload.php and app.php

Comment: If .htaccess file is in root the RewriteBase should be /

Comment: Just tried it @rajendran-nadar, still not working.

Comment: Does the form work when the .htaccess is empty or the above code is removed?

Comment: Yes, the form works, but none of the routes are working (even after typing the right one like `localhost/AxilogicV2/view/9408`.

Comment: Laravel based web apps are run via php artisan.. Probably that is the reason why you are stuck.

Comment: The app runs perfectly when run via `artisan` (in-built web server of Laravel). But when I tested it by putting it in the root folder of my wampserver the routes are not working as expected.

Comment: Where are `index.php` and `.htaccess` placed?

Comment: Both of them are placed in the root folder `AxilogicV2`